# Java doesn't load classes from manifest-defined classpath

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm using Gradle to build a project. This is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins { id 'application' }

group 'my.group'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.11

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.7.2'
}

mainClassName = 'my.group.App'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': mainClassName,
            'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { it.name }.join(' ')
        )
    }

    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    into ''
}
```

This correctly generates a jar file with the following META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: my.group.App
Class-Path: sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
[newline]
```

And in the root of this jar file, there is indeed the `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar` file referenced in the manifest; I manually verified that inside this jar file there is a class called `org.sqlite.JDBC`.

However, running the generated jar with `java -jar jarfile.jar` results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at my.group.LEManagerSqlite.<init>(LEManagerSqlite.java:64)
        at my.group.LEManager.createLEManager(LEManager.java:80)
        at my.group.GuiFrame.<init>(GuiFrame.java:60)
        at my.group.App.openFromFile(App.java:23)
        at my.group.App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
        at my.group.SqliteConnectionManager.<clinit>(SqliteConnectionManager.java:17)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at my.group.SqliteConnectionManager.<clinit>(SqliteConnectionManager.java:14)
        ... 5 more
```

For reference, `SqliteConnectionManager` has a static initializer which loads `org.sqlite.JDBC`, which is what is referenced as `SqliteConnectionManager.java:14` in the stack trace:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

I tested this with OpenJDK 11 and OpenJ9 11, with identical results. I conclude that I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot understand what.

Comment: If you downvote, kindly comment explaining why. I decided to leave the question online despite quickly finding the solution, and answer it myself, because I found many similar questions on StackOverflow with wrong answers (i.e. answers that suggest modifications to the `build.gradle` and miss the real problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong: the documentation clearly says (doh!) that the `Class-Path` directive looks for additional classpath resources in the local filesystem or the network.

Loading additional classes from jar files included in the main jar file is not supported by the JVM, and thus requires custom loading code. A simpler alternative is to unpack the additional classes from the jar files and include them directly. A jar file built this way is referred to as a "fat jar" (or "uber jar").

There is a Gradle plugin called Shadow which can build such jars without any further configuration.